# Memory management in Javascript

Tags: javascript, memory, v8

I learnt programming with C/C++, so memory management in Javascript is never intuitive to me.

I know that all variables are located in heap memory rather than in stack memory, so memory operations are quite expensive. If all references to a variable are not accessible anymore, it can be garbage collected, but it looks like V8 won't immediately do garbage collection? (Observed with `--trace_gc`)

To free memory of a global array object, this can be done by `array = null`, will `array = []` have the same effect? (I need the variable to behave like an array even after I clear it).

From my experience, `String` and `Number` are passed to functions by value while `Object` and `Array` are passed to functions by reference. If `String` is very large and the function actually allows it to be passed by reference safely (only read the string), will V8 optimizes like that?

ES6 introduces `let` keyword for block-scope declaration, but a single use of `let` makes the whole function becomes slower, so I still stick to `var` even though `let/const` are closer to C/C++ which I am familiar with. (Tested using `d8` built right from master branch, I am aware that V8 developers are actively working on this bug).

Trying to use Chrome DevTools to learn my code's memory management, but couldn't figure what those graphs and charts from profiler actually mean.

Comment: Don't spam tags. Your question has nothing to do with C++, even if you use it as a compatison

Comment: You don't really need to worry about memory in JS that much. Just let the browser take care of it.

Comment: Sounds to me that you may be trying to prematurely optimise. You can [consult this handy chart over here](https://xkcd.com/1691/) to verify if this is the case.

Comment: I like to experiment with programming syntax and learn how to write correct code (both for semantic *and* performance). I don't see this as permature optimization (I know the Knuth's famous quote)

Comment: The whole "Memory management" mindset does not apply to JavaScript. That might not be the right angle to learn to write correct code.

Comment: @JohnLondon if you think you're writing _correct_ code by trying to game the GC...umm, then you aren't. You _rely_ on specific GC and a specific engine, if you are writing a super highly performant JS code. Yet, that's not necessarily _correct_ code as it already making assumptions about performance. Assumptions that can be violated if, say, you decide to run the code elsewhere or if the implementation changes. Your code will not be correct any more. Besides, you'd probably be side-stepping runtime optimisations that the engine can apply on "normal" code.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you do c++ when you want to manage your memory and a whole bunch of quite technical stuff yourself.

If you don't want you go for c#/Java because there is a virtual machine managing the memory.

Same goes for JavaScript the browser manage the memory, and unless you're loading a page with thousands of elements  or writing a library to display / compute over thousands of data you won't have any memory problem.

Note that `array = []` will affect the reference of a new empty array when `array = null` will dereference the existing array. Since it's null, if you try to use it won't work, so go for the `array=[]`.

If you're still not convinced, then just use an appropriate library to do the work for you.